# Business time between 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp, data-science

Could you please resolve this tackle? I would like to calculate a diff of time (business time) between 2 columns of DataFrame however I get an error sth like this: 'Series' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'.

```
import datetime
import pytz
import businesstimedelta

#workday definition
    workday = businesstimedelta.WorkDayRule(
    start_time=datetime.time(6),
    end_time=datetime.time(18),
    working_days=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4])


businesshrs = businesstimedelta.Rules([workday])

#Calculate the business time between two datetimes

start = df_dur["startdate"]
end = df_dur["enddate"]

bdiff = businesshrs.difference(start, end)

print(bdiff)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df['bdiff'] = df.apply(lambda x: businesshrs.difference(x["startdate"],x["enddate"]),axis=1)
```